# How to prevent Google from asking for location permission when enabling GPS?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, gps, location-services

I took this new phone which had a notification about an update. Thinking it is like Windows OS where I must have the newest updates for proper security practices- I agreed for the update.

Turns out it has become a Lollipop device now. It wouldn't be much of a problem except that the owner who has no Google account and want to stay away from them as much as possible, sharing as little info as possible- now gets a popup every time she turns on the GPS, asking her to share her location with Google ("use Google location services").  She keeps hitting 'Decline', but other than being annoying, the demand is obviously destined to be accidentally accepted one day.

I've spent the entire day looking for a solution and I'm fairly desperate. I am not allowed to install any 3rd party GPS app on the phone nor can I revert to the previous version if it involves me downloading some file from the internet (not from an official source) and trying to flash the device (I'm inexperienced and afraid to brick the device as well).

Can anyone help?

P.S.:

- Funnily enough the popup has a "decline" button, an "accept" button, and a "don't ask me again" tick box- however when you choose the tick box- the "Decline"  button disappears (turns grey).
- I just want to add that it goes without saying about a root being out of the question.

Comment: Do you want GPS only?

Comment: Yes.       I want this phone to be able to turn on and use the GPS chip, so for instance the location could be used by an app which was installed for such purpose,  but I don't want Google to have this information unless the user has ,specifically, intentionally, chose them for one task or another.

Comment: Google Location services are managed by Google Play Services. Disable them from Settings -> Apps -> All apps and you won't see that dialog again irrespective of the location mode you choose, until you re-enable the service. This may cause trouble for un-rooted devices since some 3rd party apps ridiculously depends upon Google Location/Play services to work, and disabling them would revert back to OEM shipped obsolete package, so you must have an updated APK ready at your disposal to re-enable and update the services whenever you need Google Location Services...continued..

Comment: Also, if you re-enable Google Play Services you would have to provide your Google credentials again to the system, which would infuriate anyone who is in hurry! So, root the device I would say to avoid such issues. Ask the rooting question and you most likely would be helped.

Comment: But if privacy is the issue then why not use a firewall on your device? As long as the Google Play Services isn't getting connected to the internet, you shouldn't bother whether you agreed for Location consent or not?

Answer (score -1):

**How do you get ride of the pop up ?**

- Hi ,there is a simple solution go to `settings > location > Mode` and
  choose device only , the phone will use only the GPS sensor to get
  your location it is more than enough because any app that want to get
  your location will get your Coordinates (X,Y,and altitude too -height
  above sea level- )

**What is causing the annoying pop up ?**

- The pop up shows up becuase you choose high accuracy when you choose
  that option the phone will use ,your cell network ,wifi hot-spot and
  GPS sensor to determine your exact location in order to do so the
  phone need to send hotspot location or network antenna location.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I'm afraid however that it doesn't help. The device was already running under "device sensors only". It is true that when I tried those other options said pop up appeared as well, but when I chose 'decline' they simply didn't turn on- as oppose to my situation where upon declining the GPS works well- until the moment it is turned off and then on again. Suddenly the pop up appears.

Comment: If it helps, I see now a notification  saying :" RECENT LOCATION REQUEST: Google Play Service."

Comment: @Stupidstupidstupid ,I remember having it ,you can check the never ask again but when you do the decline button grays out ,it's like the google maps annoying tip of turning on wifi all over again.  try this too : settings > wifi >>>> click the three dots at the top right and uncheck "scanning always available"  ,also try clearing data and cache for google play services ,google play ,google framework ,chrome ,google+ any google app available (clearing data will make you lose any data on that app )

Comment: thank you for trying. the 'always scanning' box was disabled but I tried to clear data from all the "google 'something' "I saw in the  app settings ('all' category)... nope, the request for access is still there. One thing though, the "recent location requests" is now empty even though I turned the GPS on and off multiple times now.